# Enable exception printing on the webpage in Magento2

Tags: error, magento2, reports

I was installing Magento 2 and got the following error.

```
    There has been an error processing your request
    Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.
    Error log record number: 354086296325
```

In Magento 1, I used to rename `local.xml.sample` to `local.xml` in errors folder and see the exception on the webpage itself instead of checking the file in var folder. How do I do the same in Magento 2 as I don't see errors folder?

Comment: check in var/log, var/report ...

Comment: Hi, You can use developer mode to enable exception printing in magento  2. By default its set to default mode hence no exception printing.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

It's similar to Magento 1, but `local.xml.sample` is located in `pub/errors`.

Just rename `local.xml.sample` to `local.xml` within `pub/errors` directory.

Comment: use magento developer mode as well  `php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer`

Answer (score 6):

In Magento 2, **local.xml.sample** file is located in **pub/errors/**
You just need to rename **local.xml.sample** to **local.xml**
[image]

Now, the error log will not be generic but detailed like this

You can also turn on developer mode in Magento 2 by entering this line in Magento CLI: `php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer`

Referrence source: http://magentoexplorer.com/magento-exception-printing-is-disabled-by-default-for-security-reasons-how-to-fix
(This tutorial include both Magento 1 and Magento 2, scroll down you will see Debug for Magento 2)

Answer (score 0):

You can also print exception directly by modifying  magento2/pub/errors/report.php file as per below code :

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

require_once 'processorFactory.php';

$processorFactory = new \Magento\Framework\Error\ProcessorFactory();
$processor = $processorFactory->createProcessor();
if (isset($reportData) && is_array($reportData)) {
    $processor->saveReport($reportData);

    //Added code
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($reportData);
    exit;

}
$response = $processor->processReport();
$response->sendResponse();
```