# How to enable error and exception logging in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, error, api, payment

I am unable to see any type of error in magento2. i am implementing custom payment gateway but when i add a dropdown list in backend admin panel of magento2 At that time its shows blank page and when i console it shows only 500 internal server error.

Comment: Have you checked the logs? It's probably invalid XML configuration. Validate your files against the provided schema

Comment: from where i can check the logs

Comment: in    path : -------                                                                                /var/www/html/magento/var/log

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/62405/enable-exception-printing-on-the-webpage-in-magento2

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Go inside root `pub/errors` folder,

Just copy `local.xml.sample to local.xml`

Also you can enable `display_errors` from `app/bootstrap.php` file. At line no. 11 remove `#` from the start of the line.

Now the final statement displays as `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: How we can do the same things at Magento cloud environment as they are write protected.

Answer (score 0):

The techniques provided by magestore to debug https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/debug-technique-in-magento-2/