# Not all errors are displayed in var/log

Tags: magento2, log, logging, cpanel

I'm on developer mode, with a whm installed server with different cpanel accounts, our production website is on developer mode but sometimes for some products the checkout cart page show a blank page, one time i get the error in the debug log but i no longer get it displayed.
So how to enable all log errors?
Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Go inside root **`pub/errors`** folder,

Just copy **`local.xml.sample`** to **`local.xml.`**

Also you can enable **`display_errors`** from **`app/bootstrap.php`** file. At line no. 11 remove **`#`** from the start of the line.

Now the final statement displays as **`ini_set('display_errors', 1);`**

And you want to get more information follow this link -

**https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/94569/85907**

**`UPDATE:-`**

You try generate the error log using custom file :-

**https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/75954/85907**

**`THANKS.`**

Comment: I've already done this steps, but i always get the plank page and i didn't find the error in logs

Comment: Please Check my update