# Magento 2 . Model factory create fails

Tags: magento2, model, dependency-injection, factory

These are my php files.
magento\app\code\Cosmo\Basemodule\Model\DatiInterface.php

```
<?php
namespace Cosmo\Basemodule\Model;
interface DatiInterface
{

}
```

magento\app\code\Cosmo\Basemodule\Model\Dati.php

```
namespace Cosmo\Basemodule\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject\IdentityInterface;
class Dati extends AbstractModel implements DatiInterface, IdentityInterface
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Cosmo\Basemodule\Model\ResourceModel\Dati');
    }

    public function getIdentities()
    {
       //todo
    }
}
```

magento\app\code\Cosmo\Basemodule\Model\ResourceModel\Dati.php

```
<?php
namespace Cosmo\Basemodule\Model\ResourceModel;
use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb;

class News extends AbstractDb
{
    /**
     * Define main table
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('exampletable', 'entity_id');
    }
}
```

magento\app\code\Cosmo\Basemodule\Model\ResourceModel\Dati\Collection.php

```
<?php
namespace Cosmo\Basemodule\Model\ResourceModel\Dati;
use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;

class Collection extends AbstractCollection
{
    /**
     * Define model & resource model
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(
            'Cosmo\Basemodule\Model\Dati',
            'Cosmo\Basemodule\Model\ResourceModel\Dati'
        );
    }
}
```

And then block where i inject the factory
magento\app\code\Cosmo\Basemodule\Block\Main.php

```
 <?php
 namespace Cosmo\Basemodule\Block;

 use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
 use Cosmo\Basemodule\Model\DatiFactory;

 class Main extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
 {
    protected $_datiFactory;

    public  function __construct(Context $context, DatiFactory $datiFactory)
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_datiFactory = $datiFactory;
    }

    public function _prepareLayout()
    {
        echo 'pippo<br \>';
        $dati = $this->_datiFactory->create();
        var_dump($dati->getCollection());
        exit();
    }
}
```

I tried in many ways but create() fails and then nothing is executed.

Answer (score 1):

you clearly missed the interface for model

Cosmo\Basemodule\Model\DatiInterface.php

```
  <?php
    namespace Cosmo\Basemodule\Model;
    interface DatiInterface 
    {

    }
```

and your model will be

magento\app\code\Cosmo\Basemodule\Model\Dati.php

```
namespace Cosmo\Basemodule\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel;

class Dati extends AbstractModel implements DatiInterface, \Magento\Framework\DataObject\IdentityInterface
{
    /**
     * Define resource model
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
    $this->_init('Cosmo\Basemodule\Model\ResourceModel\Dati');
    }
}
```

Comment: Still not working, blank page and no errors. I can't figure it out.

Comment: @AleckSander sorry 4 late reply enable error log http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/62405/enable-exception-printing-on-the-webpage-in-magento2 and post the error in question too